# Deserialize OData to object?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, odata

My web api action returns an entity in odata json format such as is:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://x/odata/$metadata#Category","value":[
   {
      "Id":734,"Number":"100","Description":"category description"
   }]
}
```

Before using OData, I had my action return in JSON format, so I used to get the response like this:

```
var result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
```

However this method doesn't work anymore for OData JSON. How do I get to deserialize the result into my object?

Comment: You could use a native client and make the transactions by linq

Comment: Im not really sure why it matters if its an OData json or a simple JSON. They both adhere to the JSON standard?

Comment: The OData json example above cannot be deserialzed into the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several client libraries that will do the job for you. You can try OData Code Generator VS extension or Simple.OData.Client.